# Correct form, meaning

Tags: meaning

everyone.
 Here's an example:

1)"I haven't been sleeping because I was reading."

2)"I haven't been sleeping because I have been reading."

So my question is which one is correct or more natural to say.

Answer (score 2):

The second one.  This is because the mismatch of tenses in the first example is awkward.  The perfect tense and past tense do not combine well in this case, because their meanings contradict each other.

Comment: Exactly; you could say "I wasn't sleeping because I was reading" to match tenses the other way.

Comment: What about "I haven't slept because I was reading"? It sounds more natural to me.

Answer (score 0):

ostrichofevil is correct, a (more correct) alternative to your first example could be:

I wasn't sleeping because I was reading.

However all of these options are quite wordy, and as in general we aim to be concise, the following option might be even better:

Instead of sleeping, I have been/was reading.